# How do I upload my vanilla js project to blogger blogspot.com?

Tags: blogger

I've made an application in plain javascript and I want to host it in blogger i.e blogspot.com. How do I do it?

I could not find any articles for it online.

Comment: if you provide more info I can help you with that

Comment: @Bouh what information do you need, please ask.

Comment: what kind of project? is it a blog or just a plugin that you want to add to some blog? and what are the problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

edit the HTML (Theme > customize > Edit HTML), strip down the XML template, removing all non-essential elements.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:css='false' b:js='false'>
  <head>
    <b:if cond='false'><b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin></b:if>
    <!-- add head contents here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <b:if cond='false'><b:section id='section'/></b:if>
    <!-- add body contents here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

copy the files from your project to Blogger HTML editor